# Is sqlite.Net.Extensions functionalities supported in Uwp platform?

Tags: sqlite, uwp, sqlite-net-extensions

Not being able to use any SQLExtensions functionalities with Sqlite connection.

Installed SQLExtensions 2.1.0 nuget package in the UWP app, created the following db connection,

```
using (SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), DB_PATH))
        {
            conn.CreateTable<DemoType1>();
            conn.Commit();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

however I am not able to access any SQlExtension functionalities using the "conn", such as GetWithChildren or UpdateWithChildren, is there any way to use the foreign key features on UWP platform?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Accessing Write Operation:

```
SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.WriteOperations.UpdateWithChildren( SQLConnectionObject, EntityObject);
```

Accessing Read Operation:

```
 var readData = SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions.ReadOperations.GetWithChildren<Employee>(SQLConnectionObject, PrimaryKey);
```

[Tested on UWP Platform]